# Plotting 2-D time-series data on one y-axis with two properties

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot EEG (electroencephalography) data (an array of nElectrodes by nTimepoints) in python. I want to create a plot representing each electrode on the y-axis and each time point on the x-axis, but I also want the amplitude response to be represented on the y-axis. Here's an example of what I want the graph to look like (sorry for the rubbish xkcd powerpointedness of the graph):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LPqF.png

I'm having difficulty working out how to do this, particularly getting my head around giving each 'electrode' the ability to overlap with other electrodes (making artefacts much easier to spot).

I would really appreciate any help, so thanks in advance!

Darren

Comment: Did you se anything in [The Gallery](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/gallery.html) that is close to what you want?

Comment: Not really, no. The closest I can see there is subplotting, but I want to represent my data in one plot rather in many different vertically aligned plots...

Comment: AFAIK the matplotlib founder (I think it was John Hunter) started Matplotlib because he needed to do exactly these plots. So I guess it should be possible without huge effort :)

Comment: Nothing in the gallery? Not even [this example called "mri_with_eeg"](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/mri_with_eeg.html)? The overlap is merely defined by the offset (`offsets` in that example), which you can alter to your own needs. Read it, understand what you need from it, alter it and if it still doesn't work, show us the code you've tried then.

Comment: Thanks, completely missed this.

Comment: @DGMC90: if you have an answer for this, please say so.  Generally, it's best to post your answer (even if to your own question), and then mark is as your chosen answer (ie, click the check mark).

Answer (score 0):

So upon looking back at the suggestion from @sebix, the following link has a small section of plotting script at the end which seems to work well for what I want. Here's the link below:

http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/mri_with_eeg.html

I've never used offsets or anything before so this is new territory for me! Thanks for the comments.